# Preventing LINQ-injection

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a set of objects and I'd like the user to write custom queries in LINQ to objects. At the moment, I let the user enter text in a textbox like

```
from t in tests where t.Name.EndsWith("st") select t
```

then I pass that text to the LINQ "compiler", which takes that string as input and generates a class on the fly. Code:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace SecureLinqForUser
{
    internal static class LinqCompiler
    {
        public static Type Compile(string linq)
        {
            var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string> {{"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"}});
            var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] {"mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll"}, "compiledlinq.dll", true)
            {
                GenerateExecutable = false,
                GenerateInMemory = true
            };
            parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(typeof (LinqCompiler).Assembly.Location);
            parameters.CompilerOptions += " /platform:x64 ";
            var results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
                @"
            using System.Linq;
            using SecureLinqForUser;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            class Linqed 
            {
              public IEnumerable<Test> Query(Test[] tests) 
              {
                IEnumerable<Test> list = " + linq + @";
                return list;
              }
            }");

            results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));
            return results.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Linqed");
        }
    }
}
```

With that given "compiler", an untrusted user could enter things like

```
new List<Test>();
// some malicious code here, not LINQ at all
```

since there is no check that the entered text is actually LINQ. Similar to SQL injection, let's call it LINQ injection.

**Therefore my main concern is to make the code more secure. Is there e.g. a way to parse the text beforehand to ensure it only contains a single LINQ query?**

For SSCCE purposes, find the rest of the code as well:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace SecureLinqForUser
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Test[] tests =
            {
                new Test("Unit test"), new Test("System test"), new Test("Exploratory test"), new Test("Something"), new Test("Else")
            };

            var compile = LinqCompiler.Compile("from t in tests where t.Name.EndsWith(\"st\") select t;");
            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(compile);
            var list = (IEnumerable<Test>) compile.InvokeMember("Query",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                null, obj, new[] {tests});

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var test in list)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(test.Name);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public string Name;
        public Test(string v)
        {
            Name = v;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you just use OData? that would avoid the problem although, you can limit what they Query.

Comment: @johnny5: I am in an early development phase, so yes, I could basically switch to something completely different. So far I thought OData is a lot web based. I have a standalone desktop application. And the query syntax should not be too far from SQL since my users are familiar with SQL.

Comment: Have you looked into writing your own custom `QueryProvider`? With that you might be able to reject any structures you don't want them to be able to use.

Comment: @BradfordDillon: Not really. I stopped looking into that when I saw [this list](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx) of things that I have to implement myself. If I understand that right, it means to implement each keyword separately (and those articles aren't really short).

Comment: OData can be consumed easily in a desktop application,  It has a similar syntax to SQL but aside from that you can create a user for them in sql that only has certain priviledges which would at least help stop malicious attacks

Answer (score 1):

My first inclination would be to leverage linq expression trees since they are by definition a single expression and have their facilities for compiling the expression for efficient reuse. This doesn't guarantee that the expression wouldn't reach out and do anything harmful or unintended though.

My guess is that you would have to write a parser to form a DSL which is a subset of the features you want to expose to the end user. My guess is that with Roslyn being open source that it may be possible with less effort than it would otherwise be to leverage that to essentially have the Roslyn compiler fail on features you don't want to support.

Another consideration would be to add some runtime checks by loading the dynamic code within a separate AppDomain and handling Assembly Resolution and other possible hooks prevent the executing code from looking into otherwise unavailable framework features or external assemblies.

A step further could be to place the code within a separate process that has limited access to the system, perhaps by placing in a docker container, and then communicate with it on a custom communication channel.